# Jquery Ajax HTTP Post

Tags: jquery

I need to perform a silent post upon form submission. The results of that post should then be loaded into a div. The post is working just fine, but the browser is re-directing the user to the page that gets posted to as opposed to loading that page silently into the div. here is the code...

```
 $('#task_details_form').submit(function() {
            // Submit AJAX request
        $.ajax({
                url      : $(this).attr('action'),
                type     : 'post',
                data     : $(this).serialize(),
                cache    : false,
                success  : function(data) {
                        $('#user_tasks').html(data);    
                    }

                });
         return false;
     });
```

I have been playing with the syntax for a while with no success. Any ideas?

I have tried this with and without the e and still no luck.

```
$('#task_details_form').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            // Submit AJAX request
        $.ajax({
                url      : $(this).attr('action'),
                type     : 'post',
                data     : $(this).serialize(),
                cache    : false,
                dataType : 'json',
                success  : function(data) {
                        $('#user_tasks').html(data);    
                    }

                });
         return false;
     });
```

Comment: 1) comment out `$('#user_tasks').html(data);` and see if the page is redirected. 2) post what you have in the `data` variable

Comment: you only need one of these `e.preventDefault();` or `return false`

Comment: Is there any other JavaScript code on the page that could be setting another submit handler that is doing something else?

Comment: Can you recreate this problem in a jsFiddle so we can play with it?

Comment: is the redirect happening after the post request or together with it

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yfBbJ/

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the ContentType of the ajax request. add conentType

> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it'll always be sent to the server (even if no data is sent). If no
>   charset is specified, data will be transmitted to the server using the
>   server's default charset; you must decode this appropriately on the
>   server side.

```
contentType:"Application/JSON"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action from the form submission.  Normally, when you submit a form, the browser redirects from the current page to the target page.

You need to change:

```
$('#task_details_form').submit(function() {
```

to

```
$('#task_details_form').submit(function(e) {
```

and then add the following as the first line of the function:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: No luck with any of these. I'll update my code to reflect what I have tried.

Comment: @Ravi I have had problems with using `return false` in this type of situation (despite the fact that it *should* work).  I have found use of `e.preventDefault()` to be much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try, creating  a function with the ajax posting code in it and calling in on click of a button

Example

```
function PostMe(){
    var myForm = $('form#id_of_your_form');

      $.ajax({
        url      : myForm.attr('action'),
        type     : 'post',
        data     : myForm.serialize(),
        cache    : false,
        success  : function(data) {
                        $('#user_tasks').html(data);    
                    }

      });
}
```

and the button

```
<button onclick="PostMe();">Async Post</button>
```